# If $f\,\colon (0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ and $f'(x)>0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I used this in an exercise because it seemed obvious but I am not sure if it needs a proof and if yes, how would I prove it. So how do I prove that if $f\,\colon (0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ and $f$ is an increasing function then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some value $x_0\in(0,\infty)$ and observe that $f(x_0)>0$.

For each  $x\geq x_0$ we have $f(x)\geq f(x_0)>0$.

This contradicts $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: When we take limits on the last equation we get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\color{red}{\geq}0$. How do I get rid of the equal?

Comment: We get $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)\geq f(x_0)>0$

Comment: I thought that if $f(x)>g(x)$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\geq\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$

Comment: That is true, but what is the relevance of that? Do you agree that $f(x)\geq c$ for $x\geq x_0$ implies that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)\geq c$ here? That is the whole issue.

Comment: Ohhh it's greater than equal to $c$ but even if equal, $c>0$.

Comment: Yes, you grasped it. Glad to help ;).

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)>0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing. Moreover, $f:(0,\infty )\to(0,\infty )$, thus, $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in (0,\infty )$, then if $x_0>0$, $f(x_0)>0$ and for all $x>x_0$, $f(x)>f(x_0)>0$, therefore, the limit can't be $0$.